# How can I redirect to another file but keep index.php access

Tags: .htaccess

I will try to explain this in the simplest terms I can think to avoid confusing anyone.

I have a site that I've moved to a subdirectory, it will go away soon but for needs access. In the root I have a wordpress install with an index.php file.

Basically for the time being I need this:

User types www.site.com they get taken to www.site.com/comingsoon.php
User types www.site.com/index.php they get taken to that actual URL (no redirect)

This is the only line I have in my .HTACCESS:

> DirectoryIndex comingsoon.php

but that doesn't seem to work as if they go www.site.com/index.php (by typing that explicitly) they still get redirected to the coming soon page.

I can't rename the index.php from wordpress.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?$ /comingsoon.php [L]
```

This will only internally redirect `www.site.com` or `www.site.com/` to `/comingsoon.php`. But if you type `www.site.com/index.php` it should not do any redirection.

Comment: Still doing the same thing.  www.site.com/index.php still redirecting to www.site.com/comingsoon.php

Comment: Did you remove `DirectoryIndex comingsoon.php`? and Also can you tail the acccess.log when you send this request? I suspect something else is also acting in this.

Comment: I did remove DirectoryIndex....will have to check with the server (godaddy) to see if I can check the log file